# How to combine/join regular string with regex result?

Tags: python, regex, string, substitution

So I have this simple code:

```
def modify_mysql_log():
    #/var/log/mysql/mysql.log
    #Change: queries
    f=open("../mysql/mysql.log")
    t=open("../mysql/mysql2.log","w")
    for line in f:
        line=re.sub(r'Query\s*SELECT[A-Za-z\s+\W_]*\'',random.choice(queries),line)
        t.write(line)
    f.close()
    t.close()
```

Now what I am trying to do is that I want to be able to replace the line with the Query that i found with regular expression with regular expresion that i used to search with,  with random.choice(queries) combined with the regular exression result. I've looked at other re functions but somehow i cant see how to do that.

Comment: Have you try string formating functions like `"%s" % ("text")` or `"{}".format("text")` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
line=re.sub(r'REGEX', random.choice(queries), line)
```

This code will return the string obtained by replacing the "leftmost non-overlapping occurrence" of your regex with random.choice(queries). If the regex is not found you are returning line.

If I understand the problem correctly, I would try searching the line for the regex and using string.replace(string_found_by_regex, random.choice(queries) + line)